# How to check what class implements specified method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In one of Ruby examples I see the following code:

```
require 'net/http'
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new( "http://localhost:8080/" )
req.basic_auth( "user", "password" )
```

What is the easiest way to know what Ruby class actually implements this `basic_auth` method or is it dynamically generated? I have checked public_methods of `Net::HTTP::Get` and it's definitely not there. But how to check what class actually implements it?

Comment: In general, you can use something akin to `req.method(:basic_auth).owner` - _but_ this doesn't work here because `method` has been redefined in `Net::HTTP::Get`...

Comment: @Chowlett Thanks, that's exactly what i'm looking for. Maybe it's possible to call original `Kernel.method` on `Net::HTTP::Get` so redefinition will not interfere?

Comment: I couldn't figure out a way to do so; `method`'s receiver should be the object which receives the method you're interested in (because it wants to bind the method). But perhaps you can find something I can't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, you would use the `Kernel#method` method to get the `Method` object for the method in question and then you would use the `Method#owner` method to ask the `Method` object where it was defined.

So,

```
req.method(:basic_auth).owner
# => Net::HTTPHeader
```

*should* answer your question.

Except, in this particular case, that won't work because `req` is a `Net::HTTP::Get` object and `Net::HTTP::Get` overrides the `method` method to mean something completely different. In particular, it doesn't take an argument, thus the above code will actually raise an `ArgumentError`.

However, since `Net::HTTP::Get` inherits from `Object` and `Object` mixes in `Kernel`, it *is* legal to bind the `Kernel#method` method to an instance of `Net::HTTP::Get`:

```
Kernel.instance_method(:method).bind(req).(:basic_auth).owner
# => Net::HTTPHeader
```

So, there's your answer: the method is defined in `Net::HTTPHeader`.

Comment: For this particular case, as alternative, you can do this without binding method: `req.class.instance_method(:basic_auth).owner #=> HTTPHeader`

Comment: Just to clean up any misconceptions though, `Object` doesn't inherit from `Kernel`, `Kernel` is a module which `Object` includes. I realize you probably know this but I didn't want the wording to confuse anybody who may have thought the chain was `Net::HTTP::Get < Object < Kernel`. +1 Great answer!

Comment: @injekt: A mixin is just a class parameterized by its superclass :-) And mixin inheritance is inheritance. But you're right, that's not how those terms are typically used in Ruby, I'll edit that.

Answer (score 0):

I defined an `Object` method called `which` (to resemble the *nix [`which`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which) command) to discover where a method is defined.

Here is the code:

```
class Object
  def which method
    self.class.ancestors.find { |a| a.instance_methods(false).include? method.to_s }
  end
end
```

Here is how I use:

```
puts req.which :basic_auth    #=> Net::HTTPHeader
```