# How to find the module/class where a method comes from in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails, I was originally looking for a way to use the resource path helper methods (e.g. `users_path`) in models, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380703/rails-get-resource-path-in-model) gives me the answer: I can use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.users_path` .

Good, but in general and specifically in Rails, how can one find what module/class a method comes from? Are reading the source code or some official docs the only way to find it? Isn't it possible to, for example, directly check in the debug console to get `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` from `users_path` ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "namespace" in Ruby. Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "namespace"? What do you mean by "come from"? Are you asking about the module the method is defined in? Or the script location where it is defined?

Comment: Edited. Now there's no namespace.

Comment: With that clarification, your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/69149392/2988, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9003022/2988, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7247156/2988, and many others.

Comment: Hmm.. I checked your links, and `method(:users_path).owner` is actually `#<Module:0x0000000117346e18>` . How do I get `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` from this point? I couldn't find a good way.

Comment: (Please tell me if this is not about module/class and the title is not suitable.)

Comment: It feels to me like you are not interested in where a method is defined but on what object you can call that method. In your example, `users_path` is defined by meta programming and therefore you will not find a method definition with that method name at all in the code. But the method can be called on `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` on in the context of controllers and views.

Comment: @spickermann in addition there might multiple such objects. You have to identify the one "closest" to the current self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is similar to this question [How to find where a method is defined at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/175655/3577922).

In short, in Ruby 2+, (either of) the following would return an 2-element Array of the filename and line-number:

```
method(:users_path).source_location
my_object.method(:my_method).source_location
# => ["/My/Ruby/Code/some-module.rb", 123]
```

You can then work out the Module or Class name for the method.

---

**[Added in EDIT]**

To get the module name, you can use `method(:users_path).owner` instead: cf., [Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245946/determine-the-class-to-which-a-method-belongs-in-rails/7247156#7247156) and [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002556/how-to-check-what-class-implements-specified-method-in-ruby/9003022#9003022).

However, Rails uses a lot of meta programming and dynamic assignments. The url-helper like `users_path` in the question is one of them.

Quote of @spickermann's comment to the question

> `users_path` is defined by meta programming and therefore you will not find a method definition with that method name at all in the code.

Quote of @Stefan's comment to the question

> there might multiple such objects. You have to identify the one "closest" to the current self.

Specifically, `url_helpers` are defined in `actionpack-6.*/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb` for Rails 6.0 and you see the method `generate_url_helpers` is responsible to (dynamically) generate it. That is why `method(:users_path).owner` returns something like `#<Module:0x0000000117346e18>`, which is not really helpful. Even `method(:users_path).source_location` simply points to the line of

```
mod.define_method(name) do |*args|
```

(or something like that, depending on the Rails version), which indicates that the object is dynamically generated.

In consequence, I doubt if there is any easy way to *do-all* to derive a Rails object (class/module), say, `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` from the given helper function like `users_path`. But an analysis using a combination of methods like `owner` and `source_location` would be of great help to pinpoint it and might, in some cases, give you an answer you are looking for.

I note that, as far as this specific case is concerned, the error message written in `actionpack-6*.*/lib/abstract_controller/url_for.rb` would be of help – quote:

> In order to use #url_for, you must include routing helpers explicitly.
> For instance, `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`.

Comment: It's much better than no clue, but should I still actually read the code?

Comment: @akai I have edited my answer to add my version of an answer to your comment.